# Automatic Refresh of many materialized views

Tags: database, oracle, refresh, materialized-views

I have an entire schema of materialized views (about 300 tables) for which I need to perform an automatic refresh on every night. I know how to create 1 materialized view that will automatically refresh, my question is: how do I create many that need to start at the same time? Will the oracle database automatically refresh them one after another or do I need to set their start-times to be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle come with some useful utilities. In your case you can schedule a `job` to run `DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH_ALL_MVIEWS` (you can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_mview.htm#i997279)). This way you dont need to worry about handling each one of them separately

Answer (score 1):

You can run this to refresh all your views:

```
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH_ALL_MVIEWS(failures,'C','', TRUE, FALSE, FALSE);
```

You can find more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17749/refresh.htm#DWHSG8368) on **Refresh All Materialized Views with REFRESH_ALL_MVIEWS**

PS: I had miss read the post above, although the answer has already been provided, I think this might help and had more valuable information.